# Where to store my app version in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I have a **web app** (Chrome extension) that needs to read the latest version number when the app starts and force users to update if needed. The app is using Firebase.

Where in Firebase should I store the app version? Is Remote Config a good option?

Comment: yes you can store in `remote config` of firebase. its a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the version number in real-time, then I recommend storing it in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). However, if you don't need real-time updates, then you can use [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) for that.

Please also note, that there is also a [Real-time Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/real-time?platform=android) feature, but unfortunately, this feature is currently not present for the web.